# Prevent print() from emitting newlines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

i did this programme to find the even and odd numbers of n numbers entered by the user,
But this was not exactly i wanted, i want to print like ==> even numbers are 2,4,6,8....100
and odd numbers are 1,3,5,7,9....99 in a single line if the user entered n=100.
but mine print 100 lines, how can i print it in 2 lines

```
number=input("enter the numbers")
int_numb=int(number)
for i in range(1,(int_numb+1)):
    if i%2==0:
        print(f"even number{i}")
    else:
        print(f"odd number {i}")
```

Comment: You can use `end=''` in `print` if you want successive prints to be on the same line (something like `print(f"{i},", end='')`. You also should probably move the `"even number"` part outside of the loop or it will print that line for every number. Welcome to SO by the way, and I hope you have fun learning Python.

Comment: can i print like" even numbers are 2,4,6,8...,100" and also the same case for odd numbers, i tried everything to my knowledge but not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use two `for` loops (or the builtin `map` function), and the `range` function also accepts a `step` parameter which can be useful to only iterate over the even/odd numbers in a set:

```py
number = input("enter the numbers")
int_numb = int(number)

end = int_numb + 1

print('even numbers are: ', end='')

print(', '.join(map(str, range(2, end, 2))))
# or:
#  print(', '.join(str(i) for i in range(2, end, 2)))

print('odd numbers are: ', end='')
print(', '.join(map(str, range(1, end, 2))))
```

Output:

```
enter the numbers10
even numbers are: 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
odd numbers are: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
```

#### Using `for` loops

The above code is equivalent to, using only `for` loops, and `str.join` to join elements in a `list`:

```py
number = input("enter the numbers")
int_numb = int(number)

end = int_numb + 1

nums = []
for i in range(2, end, 2):
    nums.append(str(i))

print('even numbers are: ', end='')
print(', '.join(nums))

nums = []
for i in range(1, end, 2):
    nums.append(str(i))

print('odd numbers are: ', end='')
print(', '.join(nums))
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the code you posted is using generator expressions (similar to list comprehensions, but lazy iterators that don't build an actual `list`), not plain `for` loops (I'm sure you know this, but the OP is obviously very new to Python).

Comment: got it, that makes sense. I'll see if I'm able to put together the `for` loop equivalent for clarity purposes.